# Is SQL inefficient since it has to parse through everything?

Tags: sql, mysql, postgres

As you know SQL doesn't have arrays. So if you make a table "article" and wish to have comments on your articles I presume you would make another table "comment". Inside "comment" table you have the content and a foreign key named "article_id" which points to the article's id.

So to get all of the article comments you would execute this query:

```
SELECT comment.content 
FROM comment
WHERE ${specific article id} = comment.article_id
```

This is how I think you would do it.

So since the article doesn't itself have references to it's comments, the database will to iterate through *every* *single* comment posted on the website, no matter the article, to find out if the comment matches the article. So if you have thousands of articles, and each article has dozens of comments, the database has to go through tens of thousands of comments to find the few ones that match your article.
**My question is** isn't this really inefficient? Is there really no way to store dynamically the comment ids inside the article table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do You Still Need Indexing After Database Normalization](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/181730/do-you-still-need-indexing-after-database-normalization)

Comment: Your query returns every comment from every article.  If so, yes, you would have to read both tables into memory and would (presumably) do a hash join between them.  Normally, though, you'd be getting the comments for a single article in which case it would (presumably) use indexes on both tables.

Comment: @JustinCave I made a mistake, edited the post, also could you explain further what you mean?

Comment: @gnat not really what I was asking, how did you relate this to that question?

Comment: Now your query is generating a Cartesian product between the comment and article tables.  Pretty sure that is not what you want-- that would be very inefficient.  Either you want to join the tables and do something with the article data or you want to remove the article table from your query.

Comment: @JustinCave Yeah I forgot to remove that table too. So now it's correct? The original question still stands. Isn't nesting a lot more efficient than parsing through everything to see if it fits?

Comment: @korri123 you really need to read up on what database indexes are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the database has to go through tens of thousands of comments to find the few ones that match your article

No, it doesn't. This concept is called **indexes**. In basic terms, when you expect to do a search for something within a table, based on a specific column, you define this column as the index. Later, when you ask your database to return all items where `article_id` equals `123`, the database doesn't have to go through all the rows of the table; instead, through the index, it determines the matches, and reads only those matches.

This is why indexes are crucial in terms of database performance. When you'll start reading about them, you'll read about numerous cases where people went from a query which took days to the same query executing within a few seconds after proper indexes were added.

> So since the article doesn't itself have references to it's comments

Why not? This concept is called **foreign keys**. A foreign key makes it possible for you to tell that the values from this specific column of a table corresponds to the values from that column of another (or marginally the same) table.

The benefit of foreign keys is that you can't insert data which doesn't have a match within the related table. In your case, it would be impossible to have a comment with `article_id` set to `456` if there is no article with a primary key `456`.

> As you know SQL doesn't have arrays.

No, I don't. See [PostgreSQL arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html).

[Other databases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10344601/240613) let you store even XML (and traverse it).

Most SQL databases will also let you store `nvarchar(max)` which could contain a JSON of your array (or any other textual representation).

Try those alternatives, and compare their performance with a properly normalized database with proper indexes, and see by yourself which is faster to query.